# Webcam control in java

Tags: java, webcam, jmf

I am thinking of creating a project for controlling my integrated webcam in java.

I have tried searching and found that we need to use JMF for this kinda stuff.
     But i couldn't find any good tuts or books which explains JMF from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually had more success using [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) than FMJ or JMF. Here is a demo program for displaying from a webcam:

https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/DisplayWebcamVideo.java

Comment: The link to the demo app is no longer valid, please update your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following link explains JMF with nice examples:

http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html